# Add Edit Form with select element

Tags: php

I have one form that is used for adding and editing. My goal here is to on the add form have it pre-select the count(items)+1 value. On the edit form I need it to pre-select the value from the database when it it matches the increment of the for loop. Right now the $selected value isn't working and I"m not sure how to implement the part for the add form. Any ideas?

```
<?php for($x = 1; $x <= count($items)+1; $x++)
{
    if (isset($item_data))
    {
        $selected = $item_data->item_sort_order === $x ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$x.'"';
    if (isset($selected)) { echo $selected; }
    echo '>'.$x.'</option>';
}
?>
```

Comment: What's `$item_data->item_sort_order` value?

Comment: Sort Order values are increments such as 1,2,3 and so on.

Comment: As an integer, right? Not an array of values..

Comment: Well the variable $items is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to reset the `$selected` variable each time. Once its set, then it remains so. Try this:

```
for($x = 1; $x <= count($items) + 1; $x++) {
    echo '<option value="' . $x . '"';
   if ((isset($item_data) && $item_data->item_sort_order === $x)
       echo ' selected="selected";
   echo '>' . $x . '</option>';
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
for($x = 1; $x <= count($items) + 1; $x++) {
    echo '<option value="' . $x . '"';
   if ((isset($item_data) && (int)$item_data->item_sort_order == $x)
       echo ' selected="selected";
   echo '>' . $x . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Why did you take off the +1 after the count because if the last item in the database is 5 then it'll add one to the possibilities and preselect 6 in the add form

Comment: accidental omission, re added it when i noticed, usually when it comes to my loops using `count($array)`s, I prefer to omit the `+ 1` and use `<` instead of `<=`, but realised it was different in your case... I think

Comment: have you tried a `var_dump` of the `$item_data->item_sort_order`? If its an integer, then you will need to drop the strict condition `===` and replace it with `==`. Unless its important, in which case you might need to change it. I'm assuming it is an integer value, but it might be being returned as a string, so you can use `(int)` before `$item_data->...` to change it to an integer

Comment: @user1724167 I have edited the answer to include those potential changes

Comment: Awesome however for the add form it isn't showing the added extra value so if there are 3 items in the items array it doesn't show an option of 4 in the select.

Comment: @user1724167 ah, so the point of the `count(...)+1` is for pushing something to the end of the list. Do a var_dump of the `count(...)+1` and ensure the value is 4. Are you sure there are 3 items in the `$items` array?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I ran var_dump(count($items) + 1);  before the for loop and got (int) 3

Comment: then there are two items in `$items` as to get 3 from `count($items)+1`, confirm with a var_dump of just `$items`

Comment: oh wait I know what's doing this

Answer (score 0):

Just a few possible issues:

1. You never reset the variable `$selected`. That means that every item, starting with the right one, will have the attribute 'selected' set.
2. You use the strict `===` operator, which I approve of, but if `$item_data->item_sort_order` doesn't contain an int value, this comparison won't match. You can use `var_dump` to check the value *and* type of that property.
3. If there are 'holes' in your sort ordering, `$x` may never match the sort order.
4. `$item_data` is never set in your loop.

Comment: not sure entirely, but i think `$item_data` is set before the loop, so it might not be set at all (for new). But yes, `$selected` is not cleared

Comment: If it is set before the loop, then it won't change within the loop. Therefore, the condition in the `if` is the same for each iteration, making either all items selected or none at all.

Comment: don't think so, it has an inline conditional statement to check if a variable in the object matches the iteration

Answer (score 0):

Does it change anything?

```
for($x = 1, $length = count($items) + 1; $x <= $length; $x++) {
    echo '<option value="' . $x . '"' .
        (isset($item_data) && ($item_data->item_sort_order === $x) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') .
        '>' . $x . '</option>';
}
```